# Append string to variable

Tags: php

I have this:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/';

$link = <<<HTML
    <a href="$url">Link</a>
HTML;
```

Here everything works well.
Now I want to add "contact/". How? In these examples it will not work:

```
<a href="$urlcontact/">Link</a>

<a href="$url contact/">Link</a>
```

Comment: $url is just a string in your example

Comment: If you check SO there is plenty of Questions and Answers out there. So, Kindly do a quick search before your POST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [curly braces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) to separate the variable from the rest of the text:

```
$link = <<<HTML
    <a href="{$url}contact/">Link</a>
HTML;
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not directly:

```
$link = '<a href="'.$url.'contact">Link</a>';
```

Or with brackets:

```
$link = <<<HTML
    <a href="{$url}contact/">Link</a>
HTML;
```